# Can't set AWS Elastic Beanstalk static path with config file

Tags: amazon-web-services, settings, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a `config` file in my projects's `.ebextensions` directory containing

```
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
    "/static/": "sitetest/static/"
```

but my EB environment does not change the setting for `/static/` in response to this being pushed to AWS.

I can verify that other `config` settings in the same directory — e.g. for environment variables using

```
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    SOME_VAR: "foo"
```

or for container commands using

```
container_commands:
  00_syncdb:
    command: "python manage.py db upgrade"
    leader_only: true
```

behave as expected.

Why isn't AWS Elastic Beanstalk's static path changing when to correspond to the setting in my config file?

Comment: Have you tried setting the value with the web console?

Comment: Yes, no problem there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ebextensions` are a lower precedence setting. What this means is that if you ever set anything in your ebextensions using the cli/console/api, the ebextension will no longer take effect.

You can remove the setting using the cli/api in order to get the ebextension to work again.

Using the EB CLI you can use `eb config` then remove the related line from the file.

Using the AWS CLI you can use:

```
aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --environment-name MyEnvName --region us-west-2 --options-to-remove Namespace=aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles,OptionName=/static/
```

Comment: I'm no sure I follow. There's no way in the Console to remove the setting for `/static/`; I want to use my `.ebextensions/....config` file to set it.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Unfortunately no, there is no way in the console. But you only need to unset it once. (and make sure to never set it again using the console). Or, you can just set it using the console. **The ebextension will work if you create a brand new environment.**

Comment: Before I edit the scary file with `eb config`, and for reference: Is this happening because the setting I'm trying to change (`aws:elastic beanstalk:container:python:static files:`) is overridden by a *different* one: `aws:elastic beanstalk:container:python`, `StaticFiles`? Is that latter setting (and not the former) what I'm seeing in the Console? Could I change *both* in config my config files? Do I need to delete both to get things working?

Comment: Is the fact that the Console setting can't be overridden (that it causes config settings to be *ignored*, apparently without logging) documented anywhere?

Comment: @orome Is the `StaticFiles` setting in `aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python` documented anywhere? It's not on [the AWS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-specific.html#command-options-python) and the only place I've seen it so far is your comment and in the `eb config` file.